# quota exceeded without files

Tags: linux, filesystems, quota

How is it possible for a user/group to exceed its quota without owning any files? Here is an extract of my repquota output:

```
*** Report for group quotas on device /dev/mapper/lata
Block grace time: 15days; Inode grace time: 15days
                    Space limits                File limits
Group           used    soft    hard  grace    used  soft  hard  grace
----------------------------------------------------------------------
rodrigo   +-  26112K      0K      1K              0     0     1
```

Notice: 0 files, but 26112K space used!

Environment: Ubuntu Trusty (same output on Precise), ocfs2 filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if one time the partition was mounted without quota ! The user fill more than the inexisting quota. The next mount, the quota is enable and the user need to remove some files.
An other option is the administrator who drop the value of the quota to 1K.

You will maybe need a "quotacheck /dev/mapper/lata". You must check if the group is not recorded twice in /etc/group (with two different gid)

Comment: But it currently has no files in the partition! Still, 26112K used.

Comment: Do you have a directory wher you put a lot of files which can be counted in size ? find . -size +10M can help

Comment: In the particular case printed in the question, `find . -mount -group rodrigo` returns nothing.

Comment: Then it will maybe need a "quotacheck /dev/mapper/lata". Could you check if the group is not recorded twice in /etc/group (with two different gid)

Comment: it was indeed a quotafile corruption. Add your last comment to the answer, so I can "accept" it.